# Web security: reasons to not display row ID

Tags: security, web, relational-database, database-schema

**Question**. Is it bad for security to display a database table row ID for all users? If so, why?

**Background**. I am thinking of using the database table row ID in my application url, like this: www.mysite.com/product/45/tshirt_blue, where 45 is the row ID. I get the feeling this is bad for security, but I keep wondering why?

Comment: It depends - I suppose all products should be publicly available, so no security issue there. If you need some sort of access control, there might be an issue. See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A4-Insecure_Direct_Object_References

Comment: The access part should not be a problem I think. I will use a framework that handle that part. But maybe showing the ID will reveal how many rows I have in table - and maybe that is useful information for hackers?

Comment: The answer obviously depends on the sensitivity of the information you are displaying in the environment in which it is used. The same goes for any attribute whether it is an identifier or not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Referencing the primary key from your database poses a few issues, both in the security realm and the maintainability realm.

Security: Referencing your row id directly can make it quite easy to guess other products, and possibly bypass Authorization checks (AuthZ).  While you should never rely on security through obscurity to protect a system, that does not mean you have to leave instructions for regression testing your AuthZ controls all over your web app.

Maintainability: If you ever plan to have a logical entity, "Blue Seahawks T-shirt" be the same logical product, but a different db entry, 45 -> 145 for instance, this will be difficult to maintain. All links to that product will now be changed, and bookmarks and possibly search engines will be broken, unless you always map 45 -> 145, and then something else down the road.  Having an intermediary ID of some sort that you map to the appropriate DB entry in the background will allow your links to be consistent.